# SBT ignored unmanaged directory for Scala js

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an old Scala 2.11 project where one of the libraries for Scala.js is not available any more. It's a multiproject build so, I created a lib folder inside of my Scala js project and in the settings of that project set:

```
unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "lib"
```

When I go in the SBT shell to js project and type: `unmanagedBase` it shows correct path to the `lib` folder. But when I try to import the project in Intellij I'm getting this error:

```
[warn]  :: com.mediamath#scala-json_2.11;1.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.mediamath:scala-json_2.11:1.1 (/home/my_project/pg/build.sbt#L59)
[warn]        +- js:js_sjs0.6_2.11:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last js/*:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last js/*:update' for the full output.
[error] (js/*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.mediamath#scala-json_2.11;1.1: not found
[error] (js/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.mediamath#scala-json_2.11;1.1: not found
```

And I have `scala-json_2.11-1.1.jar` in my `lib` folder

Comment: Your error suggest that it is not a simple sbt project but a cross build between JVM and JS. This error shows that you are missing dependency for Scala.js rather than JVM Scala.

Comment: Yes, it's dependency of the Scala.js I specified this in my post

Comment: You provided `scala-json_2.11-1.1.jar` which requires `js:js_sjs0.6_2.11:0.1-SNAPSHOT`. It is probably a different Scala.js version than the one you are using (`1.1` vs `0.6`), and since the library is unmanaged resolver cannot try any eviction. You might try to edit its MANIFEST file to not depend on old version, but it might fail due to differences in Scala.js versions. If you have the source for the library available in any form (e.g. some `*-source.jar`) I would suggest trying to recompile it before putting it into `lib`. Or just adding it as a submodule.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment helped to resolve the issue. Would you mind to turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning

```
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.mediamath:scala-json_2.11:1.1 (/home/my_project/pg/build.sbt#L59)
[warn]        +- js:js_sjs0.6_2.11:0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

suggest that the actual issue that requires `js:js_sjs0.6_2.11:0.1-SNAPSHOT`, so some dependency related to Scala.js `0.6`, while you provided `scala-json_2.11-1.1.jar`, a JAR dedicated for Scala.js `1.1`.

Since you added a JAR as unmanaged, resolvers cannot perform evictions or suggest incompatibilities, and can merely verify whether dependencies are there or not, so you'd have to resolve them on your own.

You have some options like editing the MANIFEST file (if code would happen to be compatible between versions), or (if it's open source) compile the offending library yourself for Scala.js 1.1.